# Video Transcript for native iPhone and Android video playback player

Tags: video, videojs-transcript

Is it possible to add a video transcript to a native iPhone and Android video player? If it is not possible, what is the best possible way to satisfy Transcript/Audio description to satisfy for Accessibility.

Comment: Google for webvtt

Comment: @szatmary - Webvtt is for adding Closed captions/subtitles for videos right? Is this possible for adding a Transcript?